# Totals Sales between an amount of time

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Write a SQL query that determines and displays the total price of items sold (Total Sales) from the start of 2015 until the end of the year 2018. Use single quotes to provide the aggregate alias.

I can pull the total sale without the dates. i don't know how to specify that i only want total sale between 2015 and 2018

```
 Select sum(item.ItemPrice) as `Total Sales`
 from customer, petshop_order, petshop_order_item, item
 where petshop_order.order_date between `2015-01-01` and `2018-12-31`
 And (customer.ssn=petshop_order.ssn
 And petshop_order.OrderNo = petshop_order_item.OrderNo
 And petshop_order_item.SKU=item.SKU);
```

Error Code: 1054 unknown column '2015-01-01' in 'where clause'

Comment: try `DATE('2015-01-01')` and `DATE('2018-12-31')` instead

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quote `'` instaed of backticks i.e. ` with the dates inputs. Update your query with single quotes and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems way more complicated than it needs to be.  You are referencing tables that don't seem necessary:

```
select sum(i.ItemPrice) as Total_Sales
from petshop_order po join
     petshop_order_item poi
     using (OrderNo) join
     item i
     using (SKU)
where po.order_date >= '2015-01-01' and
      po.order_date < '2019-01-01';
```

Notes:

- Use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- The `customer` table is not needed.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Note the use of the inequalities for the date comparison.  This is safer than `between`, because the code works for dates with and without a time component.
- Note that I renamed `Total_Sales` so the column alias does not need to be escaped.

Oh, and this fixes the problem you have with the single quotes.

Comment: Thank you i know its bad... but that how its taught to us in class

Comment: @Logan . . . Your class should be updated to the 21st century.  `JOIN` was introduced probably before many of the students were born.

Comment: @Gordan Ive never taken a class like this before Im a management major....i just need to satisfy a grad requirement Im assuming the Professor thought this was easier but who knows. Im sorry its so bad but i do appreciate the help.